# Cursor out of bounds exception when inserting values to Database - Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to insert values from a cursor to my database, but I get an error.

Here's what I do -

```
    Cursor getUserDrinks = myDbHelper.getUserDrinks();
    if(getUserDrinks != null)
    {
        if (getUserDrinks.moveToFirst()){
               do{
                    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                    initialValues.put("code", getUserDrinks.getInt(getUserDrinks.getColumnIndex("code")));
                    initialValues.put("imgstr", getUserDrinks.getString(getUserDrinks.getColumnIndex("imgstr")));
                    initialValues.put("name", getUserDrinks.getString(getUserDrinks.getColumnIndex("name")));
                    initialValues.put("alc", getUserDrinks.getDouble(getUserDrinks.getColumnIndex("alc")));
                    initialValues.put("user", 1);

                    try {  
                           myDataBase.beginTransaction();
                           myDataBase.insert("drinks", null, initialValues);
                           myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
                           } 
                       finally {
                           myDataBase.endTransaction();
                           }
               }while(getUserDrinks.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

But it gives me a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here's the Log -

```
04-30 13:22:35.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19161): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to         start activity ComponentInfo{android.alco/android.alco.main}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
```

I know that the Cursor is not empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't recognize the Java code. Would appreciate if someone could fix it for me, because I couldn't get it right. Thanks!

Comment: You have to put four spaces at the beginning of each line if you want the text to be treated like code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `moveToNext()` returns `false` when you are already positioned after the last element and want go further. Range of valid positions is from -1 to `elementCount` inclusive, so the last position is legitimate, but there's no element. This is what really happens in your code if the cursor has two positions:

1. You call `moveToFirst()`, cursor is positioned at the first element with index 0.
2. You read the values and call `moveToNext()`. Movement succeeds, you are positioned at index 1.
3. You read the values and call `moveToNext()`. Movement succeeds, you are positioned at index 2, which is beyond the last element.
4. You try to read the values and fail because there is no element with index 2.

What you need to do is the following:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    //Read the contents
    cursor.moveToNext(); //Advance to the next element
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that partly worked. I don't get an error now, but for some reason the value are not inserted to the database. The program just keeps running without showing an error, but the values are not entered for some reason...

Comment: I suppose this is a topic for a different question, there isn't enough information to answer it right now. This part of the code seems fine to me, the problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a different question, because it still doesn't insert the values. There isn't really much more to it, I don't have any more information to give. I really don't know what to do here, since inserting works fine in other sections of the app.

Comment: I said about a new question because initial question was basically how to properly iterate through cursor's contents. As for the new question about not working insertion, I don't know the structure of the tables, their contents or how you check if something has been inserted. You should first of all check what `myDataBase.insert()` returns. Also there's no need to explicitly start and end transaction, this only makes sense when you perform several operations in one transaction.